# storage for uploaded images on a web farm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cluster-computing, web-farm

I work on mvc.net application. Client is going to move production on a cluster environment.
The problem is I store images in the local file system. Images can be dynamically uploaded by users through web site interface. How can I change the application in order to keep the images in working state?

The possible solution is the using of shared folder for all servers, but in that case I think I have to develop HttpHandler which will return images from this folder. So, it can affect the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The possible solution is the using of shared folder for all servers, but in that case I think I have to develop HttpHandler which will return images from this folder. So, it can affect the performance.

Another option is to have a separate server dedicated to serving images & static files. You can tune it up for that purpose. When a file is uploaded, it goes to that server (which could or not be done through the other servers).

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea. But there is one disadvantage here - maintenance of a separated web server.

Comment: And I have a question to you: what is a  better practice to write files to this server: just write them directly in the shared folder on this server or create a web service method which requires file and it's path?

Comment: its a matter of how loosely coupled you want your environment. I'd really just use the network share for now, and only when needed move to a web service i.e. if you need to put in more than 1 place, run any pre-processing of the images/videos, etc. This is highly dependent on your specific environment and where you want to put the load / even processing queues would be used if the load were extremely high.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a CDN such as [Amazon's S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3).

Comment: Client wants to avoid 3-rd party services